# iOS Storing the UISegmentedControl selection in NSUserDefaults

Tags: iphone, nsuserdefaults, uisegmentedcontrol

Is there some way to store a UISegmentedControl value into NSUserDefaults? 
Should I use it like the integer value in NSUserDefaults?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd simply use the selectedSegmentIndex: method of the [UISegmentedControl](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/Reference/UISegmentedControl.html) and then use the setInteger:forKey: method within [NSUserDefaults](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html). The reason for this (as you seem to be hinting at in your question) is that the selectedSegmentIndex method returns an NSInteger. (Its full method signature is: `@property(nonatomic) NSInteger selectedSegmentIndex`)

When you reload your app, you'd then set the corresponding segment to active (once again via selectedSegmentIndex).

However, unless you're setting a default (via Interface Builder, or programatically), you should check the returned selectedSegmentIndex integer against the UISegmentedControlNoSegment constant to make sure you're not attempting to store what is effectively "no selection".